# Is it possible to use AJAX to send mail using the 'Outlook Anywhere' feature?

Tags: http, outlook, exchange-server, rpc

The Outlook Anywhere Microsoft Exchange Proxy Settings dialog includes the following:

> Microsoft Outlook can communicate with Microsoft Exchange over the
>   internet by nesting Remote Procedure Calls (RPC) within HTTP packets. 
>   Select the protocol and the identity verification method that you want
>   to use.  If you don't know which options to select, contact your
>   Exchange Administrator.

So I am curious if it would be possible to set up a web app that uses my corporate email to send and receive mail?  Seems like I should be able to since it is just using HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You really would not want to code against RPC over HTTP (which is not documented) or MAPI-over-HTTP (which is also not documented).

What you can do is use Exchange Web Services API (which is pure HTTP) - see [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx)